# Android - Load a Bitmap without alterations

Tags: android, bitmap

I need to use a specific png to create a bitmap. This bitmap must contain the EXACT values of my png. When loading it with BitmapFactory.decodeResource() the values get altered. I tried openRawResource and put my png in drawable/raw folder. I do not intend to draw that picture. The only thing in need to do is using that bitmap for getPixel requests.

Why are the bitmap values still altered?

Comment: I had a similar problem a while ago. Check out [this][1] question.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4033292/android-2-2-distorts-picture-colors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try creating a folder called `res/drawable-nodpi` and place your .png file in that.

From the Android [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) documentation:

"If you have some drawable resources that the system should never scale (perhaps because you perform some adjustments to the image yourself at runtime), you should place them in a directory with the nodpi configuration qualifier. Resources with this qualifier are considered density-agnostic and the system will not scale them."